# Extended Quantity

Tags: excel, performance, excel-formula

Good afternoon,

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a better approach for finding the extended quantity of a row (based on level.)  The dataset looks similar to this:

| Level | Component | Quantity | ExtQty (formula) | Purchase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | complete component 1 | 2 | 2 | M |
| 2 | component 2 | 4 | 8 | P |
| 3 | component 3 | 4 | 0 | M |
| 2 | component 4 | 4 | 8 | M |
| 3 | component5 | 10 | 80 | M |
| 1 | complete component 2 | 1 | 1 | M |
| 2 | component2 | 4 | 4 | P |
| 3 | component3 | 4 | 0 | M |
| 2 | component8 | 4 | 4 | M |
| 3 | component9 | 10 | 40 | M |

I'm using:
`=@IF(A2-1<1,C2,IF(XLOOKUP(A2-1,$A$2:$A2,$E$2:$E2,"ERR",0,-1)="P",0,XLOOKUP(A2-1,$A$2:$A2,$D$2:$D2,"ERR",0,-1)*$C2))`

Currently it's still inserting over 184,000 rows and it's been about 50 minutes, still going...
(edit: finished at 53 minutes)

The goal is to take the quantity and multiply it with the quantity of the levels above.  If the parent is a purchase part, set quantity to 0.

Does anyone have any tips to make this a little faster, other than working with a smaller dataset?

Comment: is there a good number of rows that one can reliably set that would always include the preceding level?  Maybe limiting the search to the last 100 rows?  If this is possible it would greatly decrease the calc times.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I build train cars and each car is about ~10000 lines (components), and is  different for each car.   It's a good thought to start "$A$2", "$E$2", and "$D$2" at the latest "Level 1", but that means more lookups I'd imagine.

Comment: What would be the maximum number of levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with VBA.  Currently running 184000 rows in 20 seconds rather than 53 minutes.

I'm not great at VBA, but this is what I came up with:

```
Sub ExtQty()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim levelStack, stopStack As Object
    Dim lvlCol, extQtyCol, qtyCol, procCol, bomCol, itemCol, compCol As Integer
    Dim Progress As Double
    Dim i, j As Long
    
    Set sheet = Application.ActiveSheet
    ProgressForm.Show (vbModeless)
    lRow = lastRow()
    qtyCol = GetColumn("Quantity")
    extQtyCol = qtyCol + 1
    sheet.Columns(extQtyCol).Insert shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    sheet.Cells(1, extQtyCol).Value = "ExtQty"
    lvlCol = GetColumn("Level")                                             'after ExtQty insert for correct column
    procCol = GetColumn("Procurement")
    compCol = GetColumn("Component")
    itemCol = GetColumn("Item")
    Set levelStack = CreateObject("System.Collections.Stack")
        
    sheet.Range(Cells(2, itemCol), Cells(lRow, itemCol)).Font.Bold = True
    sheet.Range(Cells(2, compCol), Cells(lRow, compCol)).Font.Bold = True
    sheet.Range(Cells(2, extQtyCol), Cells(lRow, extQtyCol)).Font.Bold = True
    
    i = 1
    For Each cell In sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(2, lvlCol), sheet.Cells(lRow, lvlCol))
        Call ProgressForm.Progress(i, cell.Row, lRow, 1000)                 'every 1000 loops; every loop hurts performance
        If cell.Offset(1, 0).Value > cell.Value Then                        'push parent level onto stack
            If cell.Value = 1 Then
                sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), extQtyCol).Value = sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), qtyCol).Value
            Else
                If levelStack.Peek()(1) = "F" Then
                    sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), extQtyCol).Value = 0
                Else
                    sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), extQtyCol).Value = sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), qtyCol).Value * levelStack.Peek()(0)
                End If
            End If
            levelStack.Push Array(sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), extQtyCol).Value, sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), procCol).Value)
        ElseIf cell.Offset(1, 0).Value < cell.Value Then                    'check if leaving current level and pop
            If cell.Value = 1 Then
                sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), extQtyCol).Value = sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), qtyCol).Value
                If cell.Row >= lRow Or cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then    'fixed error if last row AND level 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            ElseIf levelStack.Peek()(1) = "F" Then
                sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), extQtyCol).Value = 0
            Else
                sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), extQtyCol).Value = levelStack.Peek()(0) * sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), qtyCol).Value
            End If
            
            If cell.Value > cell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
                diff = cell.Value - cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
            End If
            
            For j = 1 To diff                                               'used for when level drops more than one level
                If cell.Row() = lRow Then
                    topStack = levelStack.Clear()
                    Exit For
                Else
                    topStack = levelStack.Pop()
                End If
            Next
        Else                                                                'All others - don't push or pop
            If cell.Value = 1 Then
                sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), extQtyCol).Value = sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), qtyCol).Value
            ElseIf levelStack.Peek()(1) = "F" Then
                sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), extQtyCol).Value = 0
            Else
                sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), extQtyCol).Value = levelStack.Peek()(0) * sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), qtyCol).Value
            End If
        End If
        sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), extQtyCol) = Round(sheet.Cells(cell.Row(), extQtyCol), 3)
    Next
    ProgressForm.Hide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the table does not express the same behavior in each row, for example, I understand that in Level 3 = 10 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 80, but the Level 2 = 4 * 2. It does not have a fixed rule. In case you want to use the first it's "=POWER(2;A6)*C6" and otherwise "=POWER(2;A5-1)*C5"

Comment: I think you might be reading it wrong, or I'm misunderstanding you.  The second level 3 is 2 * 4 * 10 = 80.  The fixed rule is to take the quantity and multiply it with the quantity of the levels above.